# Powershell & Excel - manipulating user forms?

Tags: excel, powershell, userform

If you have a userform (userform1)  that has a textbox (textbox1) and an exit button (commandbutton1), how do you manipulate (i.e., edit) the textbox entry with powershell and then have powershell click the exit button on the userform?

I'm new to powershell/excel and have been banging my head with how to manipulate userforms.  I've got powershell to open excel and start a macro that loads my userform, but now I'm stumped as to how to manipulate it.

Comment: If you want PowerShell to manipulate a Form, it would be much better to create the form from PowerShell. i.e PowerShell creates a Form, PowerShell starts Excel and PowerShell manages all interactions. Forget about macros :)